# Is it caustic reflection or hyperbolic projection?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, geometric-optics

actually last night I noticed a strange form of light rays on the wall of my room which were reflected off a CD. Here is its photo:

[image]

Please let me know what is it exactly? A caustic projection or hyperbolic form of reflection or what else?

If we have a camera with infinitive zoom ability, is it possible to expose the data which is written on this CD or not? I mean does the pattern of these reflected light rays represent the pattern of bits written on this CD?

Appreciate your all answers in advance,